# Intellij IDEA cannot format file type ftl

Tags: intellij-idea, freemarker, file-type

I want to create sevaral .ftl file type but Intellij can't recognize this type and I even can't open it. There is no type for these file, just question marks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working with FreeMarker template language is possible using the bundled plugin only:

[image: Bundled FreeMaker pugin]

This feature is only supported in the Ultimate edition:

[documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-data-languages.html)